# Bitbucket Pipelines: Issue with cd command in script, directory not found

Tags: bitbucket-pipelines

I'm currently working on a CI/CD pipeline with Bitbucket. I'm facing an issue where I am trying to change into a directory using the cd command, but Bitbucket throws an error indicating the directory does not exist.

Here's a snippet of my pipeline configuration:

```
pipelines:
  branches:
    master:
      - step:
          name: update gitops image tag
          script:
            - git clone https://x-token-auth:$TOKEN@bitbucket.org/myuser/myrepo-gitops.git
            - VERSION="prod-0.1.${BITBUCKET_BUILD_NUMBER}"
            - sed -i "s/\([ ]*image:[ ]*mydockerregistry.com\/myapp-ui\:\)\(.*\)/\1"${VERSION}"/" myrepo-gitops/myapp_ui/docker-compose.yml
            - cat myrepo-gitops/myapp_ui/docker-compose.yml
            - ls -d */
            - cd ./myrepo–gitops/myapp_ui
            ...
```

When running the pipeline, everything works until the cd command:

```
+ ls -d */
android/
myrepo-gitops/
ios/
public/
src/
tests/
bash: cd: ./myrepo–gitops/myapp_ui: No such file or directory
cd ./myrepo–gitops/myapp_ui
```

It seems the directory exists, but there's an issue with the cd command. Any insights on what might be causing this?

Comment: Does the `cat` command you run before `cd` work properly?

Comment: why include the `./` in the cd?

Comment: Yes every thing before cd running without error. I include ./ while debugging the error. With out I get the same error message.

Comment: if you start by doing `cd ./myrepo-gitops` and the run `ls -d */` what do you get? Is the folder there?

Comment: still same error

````
git clone https://x-token-auth:$TOKEN@bitbucket.org/myuser/myrepo-gitops.git
1s
+ git clone https://x-token-auth:$TOKEN@bitbucket.org/myuser/myrepo-gitops.git
Cloning into 'myrepo-gitops'...
ls -d */
<1s
+ ls -d */
android/
myrepo-gitops/
ios/
public/
src/
tests/
bash: cd: myrepo–gitops/myapp_ui: No such file or directory
cd myrepo–gitops/myapp_ui
+ cd myrepo–gitops/myapp_ui
````

Comment: also reduced script to: 

````
git clone ...
- ls -d */
            - cd myrepo–gitops/myapp-ui
            - pwd
            - ls -d */
````
and tried `cd ./myrepo–gitops/` `cd myrepo–gitops/` `cd myrepo–gitops`

Comment: What docker image is being used to run that step script?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

After many attempts, I changed the name from `myrepo-gitops` to `myrepo_gitops`. After this change, the pipeline executed without issues. Upon further testing, I found that both name variants were usable.

I suspect there may be a bug in Bitbucket, but I can't reproduce it any longer.

**Conclusion:** I'm closing this issue. Big thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: is that the actual name of the folder or a placeholder?